# Compute number formed by the K-th lexicographic permutation of a given multiset of digits in modulo

Tags: algorithm, combinatorics

You are given **Q** queries. Each query gives you a multiset **S** of digits 0 through 9 and an integer **k**. You are asked to determine the integer representation of the **k-th** lexicographic permutation of **S**, **modulo 10^9+7**.

Restrictions and other notes:

- k<=10<sup>12</sup>
- Q<=5000
- S contains at most 70.000 digits
- The integer represented by a permutation of order n,  p={p<sub>n-1</sub>,p<sub>n-2</sub>,...,p<sub>1</sub>,p<sub>0</sub>} is equal to the sum of p<sub>i</sub>*10<sup>i</sup>, for all i from 0 to n-1. As an example, the permutation {2,0,1} gives the integer 201. The permutation can also start with multiple 0-s, such that, for example, the permutation {0,0,0,1,2} will give the integer 12.
- time limit 2 sec

Some examples:

- For S={0,1},k=1, the result will be 1.
- For S={0,1},k=2: 10
- For S={0,1,2},k=1: 12
- For S={0,1,2},k=2: 21
- For S={0,1,2},k=5: 201
- For S={0,1,1},k=2: 101

I'm having problems finding an efficient enough solution. I tried finding the k-th permutation via the usual method, then simply calculating the modulo, but it isn't fast enough. The modulo really changes things quite a bit, I think.

I've also observed that k is relatively small compared to the number of possible permutations,so this might make room for some optimizations.

Comment: What programming contest does this question come from?

Comment: @rici http://www.infoarena.ro/algoritmiada-2017 It's the problem called qnp.

Answer (score 1):

> I tried finding the k-th permutation via the usual method

Not sure what your usual method is. k-th permutation can be obtained in O(|S|) time, I'm assuming you're using that.

> then simply calculating the modulo, but it isn't fast enough

Notice that you have the same size of S for multiple queries. You should build array D, D[i] = 10^i % M, then for each given permutation simply find sum of D[i]*S[p[i]] % M - once again, linear time.

Actually since k < 15! only last 15 digits change their order, everything before them needs to be computed only once for all queries.

Comment: Oh, my bad. I didn't write the problem statement correctly. You are given a multiset of digits for each query.

Comment: Then you would need to store D between calls and expand as needed (or create all 70000 elements right away, it should be well within time constraint). Anything else doesn't change.

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm currently doing, precalculating all the powers of 10. However, I'm not currently optimizing by only taking into consideration the last 15 digits. Let's see if that does the trick...